# How to make wxPython class browser

Tags: python, wxpython

How do I implement a class browser in wxPython? Should I scan the whole code, or there is a function for this in wxPython?

Comment: You'll have to describe in a lot more detail what you mean by "a class browser". Are you trying to browse all the classes in the current interactive environment? In a single script? In a script and everything it imports? In a directory full of scripts? In a "project" defined in some way?

Comment: Meanwhile, whatever your answer, wx isn't going to have anything for scanning Python source or introspecting the interactive environment or anything like that; it's just a GUI library. But the Python standard library has all kinds of things—[`inspect`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/inspect.html) for live objects, [`ast`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html) to parse source, etc.

Comment: @abarnert, I mean I want to get **all** the classes (and their functions if possible) in a string. Thanks for the links, I will take a look.

Comment: "A string" meaning "a hunk of Python source code"? And does "all the classes" include classes defined inside functions or methods, or even classes created dynamically? Or just the top-level classes? Or whichever classes would end up being defined if you executed/imported the code? Or…?

Comment: I might be misunderstanding you but ulipad, a wxpython based editor, has a built in class browser. You might see how they do it. http://code.google.com/p/ulipad/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question isn't entirely clear about what you want, but I'll make some assumptions and show you how to do one of the possible interpretations of what you're asking.

I'll assume you have a string with the contents of a Python script, or a fragment from your cut-and-paste repository, or whatever, and you just want to know the top-level classes defined in that string of source code.

You probably don't want to execute that code. For one thing, who knows what arbitrary strange code can do to your environment? For another, if you're building a class browser, you probably want it to work on code that's depends on other code you may not have access to, so you *can't* execute it.

So, you want to parse it. The easiest way to do that is to get Python to do it for you, using the [`ast`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/ast.html) module:

```
import ast

with open('mymodule.py') as f:
    mycode = f.read()

myast = ast.parse(mycode)
for thing in myast.body:
    if isinstance(thing, ast.ClassDef):
        print('class {}({})'.format(thing.name, 
                                    ', '.join(base.id for base in thing.bases)))
        for subthing in thing.body:
            if isinstance(subthing, ast.FunctionDef):
                print('    def {}'.format(name))
```

When I run this against, say, the ast.py from Python 3.3's stdlib, I get this:

```
class NodeVisitor(object)
    def visit
    def generic_visit
class NodeTransformer(NodeVisitor)
    def generic_visit
```

If that's not what you wanted, you'll have to explain what you *do* want. If, for example, you want all class definitions, even local ones within functions and methods… well, the names of those two classes just dumped out above should help.